# How to know if a tab is enabled on jQuery tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I can't find in the API of jQuery UI Tabs ( http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) a method to know if a certain tab is enabled or not, I need that because in an event of my application I want to enable a certain tab only if that tab is disabled.

Do you know how can I get that information from the jquery api?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `disabled` option returns an aray of he indexes of the disabled tabs, so a function to check if one's disabled would look like this:

```
function isDisabled(index) {
  return $.inArray(index, $("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled")) > -1;
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JTp5k/), this just uses [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to see if the index is present, just remember the index is `0` based, so the 1st tab is `0`, 2nd one is `1`, etc.

Comment: It is not working for me. I am using jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js and jquery-1.9.1.js. Could you please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there (it's on your link): [disabled](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-disabled)

```
//getter
var disabled = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "disabled" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: I don't get it, where did I pass the index of the tab I want to know if it's enabled?..

Comment: the //getter line will set the value of the variable 'disabled' as a jQuery object. So, if you want to see which one it is, you can request disabled.attr('id'), etc.

Comment: and what if there's more than one tab disabled, in that case I think your example wont work..

Comment: The code I pasted (copied from that link by the way) shows you if a single tab is disabled. If you want to check if **another** tab is disabled, use a different selector. Have you ensured each one of your tabs has a unique ID?