# how to check if jquery UI Tabs is unactive

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently working with jquery UI Tabs I want to check if a Tab is currently unactive I checked the wiki and I saw that there is enabled and disabled option but that didn't work is there any work around that i can do ?

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
     if($("#Tabs").inactive){
        // do something
         }
    </script>
```

Comment: A little more explaining please?

Comment: i edited my title and my question please check

Comment: Do you mean tab is active or inner tabs are active?

Comment: i mean not selected or not focused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", 2);
  });
</script>
```

or multi-disable

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs('option','disabled', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
</script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [2]);
  });
</script>
```

to enable tab and move to use

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "enable" , 1 )
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "select" , 1 )
```

*counting starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

From jquery UI;

Get or set the active option, after initialization:

```
// getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

I hope this will hep you.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery UI doesn't have that method but you can implement your own. Something like this:

The disabled option returns an array of he indexes of the disabled tabs, so a function to check if one's disabled would look like this:

```
function isDisabled(index) {
  return $.inArray(index, $("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled")) > -1;
}
```

See the link below for more info:
[How to know if a tab is enabled on jQuery tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625198/how-to-know-if-a-tab-is-enabled-on-jquery-tabs)