# How to get array of disabled tab index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I have disabled the tabs for jquery tabs. I am using `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js` and `jquery-1.9.1.js`. I want to traverse back and forth for the visible tabs. But it is pointing to the disabled tabs. I have two button next and previous and which performs call there functios as below on onclick. I use the below code as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625198/how-to-know-if-a-tab-is-enabled-on-jquery-tabs)

```
 function OnNextButtonClick()
             {
              var index= $('#ui-tabs').tabs("option", "active");
              var size=$('#ui-tabs >ul >li').size();
                for(var i=index+1;i<size;i++){

                   if(isDisabled(i))
                   {
                      continue;
                   }else{
                    $('#ui-tabs').tabs('option', 'active',i);
                    break;
                   }
                   }                 
             }
function OnPrevButtonClick()
             {
              var index=$('#ui-tabs').tabs("option", "active");

                for(var i=index-1;i>=0;i--){

                   if(isDisabled(i))
                   {
                  continue;
                   }else{
                    $('#ui-tabs').tabs('option', 'active',i);
                    break;
                   }
                }      
             }

 function isDisabled(index) {
            return $.inArray(index, $("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled")) >-1;
        }
```

But it is not working for me, function `isDisabled` gives me wrong result. How do I get the list/array of disable tab index. Please assist.

Comment: Can you please include all your code, as well as the snippet for determining if a tab is disabled.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan : I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used a wrong tab element id(`tabs` instead of `ui-tabs`) in the method `isDisabled`

```
function isDisabled(index) {
     return $.inArray(index, $("#ui-tabs").tabs("option", "disabled")) > -1;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s66ZQ/)