# Iterate over enabled tabs in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can iterate over all tabs using the following code

```
$('#tabs .ui-tabs-nav a').each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

(courtesy of https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-iterate-through-tabs)

I can check to see if a tab is enabled via its index using the following code

```
function isDisabled(index) {
  return $.inArray(index, $("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled")) > -1;
}
```

(courtesy of Nick Craver from [How to know if a tab is enabled on jQuery tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625198/how-to-know-if-a-tab-is-enabled-on-jquery-tabs))

How do I iterate over all enabled tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$.filter` to remove the ones that are disabled, and then `$.each` over the remaining:

```
$('#tabs .ui-tabs-nav a').filter(function(index) {
    return !isDisabled(index);
}).each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Or you could `$.not`:

```
$('#tabs .ui-tabs-nav a').not(isDisabled).each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
});
```